How to combine 2 lists into 1 list in Excel?
I have 2 lists. It looks something like this
    A        B        C
1  Anna    Eddie
2  Brenda  Fred
3          Jason
4          Huang
5          Kris

What I'd like to do is combine them into column C, so the result would be
    A        B        C
1  Anna    Eddie     Anna
2  Brenda  Fred      Brenda
3          Jason     Eddie
4          Huang     Fred
5          Kris      Jason
6                    Huang
7                    Kris

The order I've demoed in column C is not relevant (or desired). As long as the new column combines everything, that is all that matters
The advice I've seen online demos concat which isn't what I want as I want 1 entry per cell.
In the example above, I have only 2 entries in column A, but my real application might have more or less and change each day (the next day there might be 8 entries (or 100). The same is true for column B)

If you have Excel 365, use TOCOL function. The 1 is to ignore empty cells
=TOCOL(A1:B5,1)



For older excel this may be useful:
=IFERROR(IF(ROW($A$1:INDEX(A:A,COUNTA($A$1:$B$100)))>COUNTA($A$1:$A$100),INDEX(B:B,ROW($B$1:$B$100)-COUNTA($A$1:$A$100)),$A$1:$A$100),"")
Not sure if it requires being entered with cttl+shift+enter
